# validation rule making a field mandatory only if created after specified date

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I want to make a field mandatory only on records created after a specified date.  So if the opportunity created date is prior to current date then field wouldn't be mandatory but if opp. created date is = current date or later then field is mandatory.  Is there a way to write that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try validation rules like;

Error Condition :

```
AND (NOT( ISNULL(CreatedDate  ) ), (TODAY() > DATEVEALUE(CreatedDate) ), ISNULL(f2__c ) )
```

**NOT( ISNULL(CreatedDate  ) )** : Will allow new records to be created without checking for f2__c

**TODAY() > DATEVEALUE(CreatedDate)**  : This will check records that are not created today.